# Gitlab ce filter by filename in push

Tags: gitlab

I have a Gitlab CE, and I want to know if you can filter files in push by extension in GitLab CE, for example, does not accept .exe?

Answer (score 0):

there are the gitignore file to manage this :

[Gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: I want to do a check gitlab side and not client side

Comment: in git we don't have a client-server architecture like cvs and svn but a distributed architecture, so when you ignore some files in your local repo it's will be ignored when you do a push the best practice is to create the ignore file in the beginning  of your project